# How to map the response object to array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am looking to map one of my response objects to the existing array of objects by running two different loops, somehow I am not able to remove the value if the matched key is not found in the object.

Is there any way I can make the value null if the keys don't match?

I tried following:

```js
const data = {
  test1: 1,
  test2: 2
};

const val = [
  {
    id: 'test1',
    val: 2222
  },
  {
    id: 'test2',
    val: 5555
  },
  {
    id: 'test3',
    val: 4444
  }
];

val.forEach(element => {
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (element.id === key) {
      element.val = value;
    }
  });
});

console.log(val);
// output:
// const val = [
//   {
//     id: 'test1',
//     val: 1
//   },
//   {
//     id: 'test2',
//     val: 2
//   },
//   {
//     id: 'test3',
//     val: ""
//   }
// ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. Just check if the property exists.

```js
const data = {
  test1: 1,
  test2: 2
};

const val = [{
    id: 'test1',
    val: 2222
  },
  {
    id: 'test2',
    val: 5555
  },
  {
    id: 'test3',
    val: 4444
  }
];

val.forEach(element => {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(element.id)) {
    element.val = data[element.id];
  } else {
    element.val = "";
  }
});

console.log(val);
```